# How to store and update data from one excel interface (Sheet 1) to another sheet (Sheet 2) to keep track on the transaction history?

Tags: excel, vba

I have faced a problem during my project. I want to store Entered Data of a sheet (Sheet1) to another sheet (Sheet2) to save my history of the transactions. Important thing is that after every input in the Sheet1, it should go back to the blank cell (Sheet1) so that a new entry can be done in that particular cell (Sheet1) again. And during this process, I want to store those values to Sheet2 on a regular basis so that I can keep track on the history. 
I have tried the following on VBA but it does not work.

```
Sub Master_Sheet_Record()
If Sheet1.Range("D1") = "" Then
MsgBox "OK"
Else
Sheet1.Range("D1").Copy
Sheet2.Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
End Sub
```

I have written this in a module. 
That bold line of the code should be in a way such that after each entry that B2 change to B3 so that it can store the next input of Sheet1.

Please do respond to the mail and guide me if possible.

Comment: tip: instead of `copy/paste`, use `Sheet2.Range("B2").value = Sheet1.Range("D1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a *history*, then you need an event macro.

Place the following in the *Sheet1* code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r = Range("A1")
    If Intersect(r, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "" Then
            r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
        Else
            N = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            r.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(N, 1)
        End If
        r.Clear
        r.Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Every time a value is entered in *Sheet1* cell **A1**, that value is copied to the bottom of the list of historic values in *Sheet2* column **A**.  *Sheet1* cell **A1** is cleared and re-selected.

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

Comment: Can I use this code for multiple cells?? @Gary's Student

Comment: @SOUVIKDAS  yes.....do you need a separate history column for each cell being tracked??

Comment: Yes...I need a separate history column for each cell. Actually, in my project, 
I have to track 3 cell's input. But when I use the code for 3 cell's then the code goes wrong.  @Gary's Student

Comment: @SOUVIKDAS  What are the three cell addresses ??

Comment: Input cell addresses are A1, B1, C1(Sheet1) and those inputs should be stored in the cells A1, B1, C1(Sheet2).